# Line brakes between paragraphs on Page Content Field

Tags: publishing-site, master-page, page-layout

I have SharePoint publishing site, just a basic staff - few CQWP and Page Content Field. The problem with my page content field is that it put line brakes between my paragraphs or lines in a sentence.

Do you think this has something to do with my master page or perhaps page layouts?

Your assistance will be highly appreciated.

Kind Regards,
Sep

Answer (score 1):

probably you have some custom CSS that apply this line break after paragraphs. Use firebug and check what CSS is attached to that paragraph.